# PHP PDO Connect sometimes takes a long time to connect using mysql percona

Tags: mysql, percona

I have a more or less simple application, written in php 7.4, using PDO to connect to my database. This connect usually takes under 0.0002 seconds > we are talking about 99.9% of my requests. On very rare times, i got peaks up to 1 second, just to connect to the database server via PDO.

My snippet to connect to my database looks like this:

```
            $conn_string = $cred['driver'] . ':dbname=' . $cred['database'] . ';host=' . $cred['host'];
            if (!isset(self::$connection)) {
                $start = microtime(true);
                self::$connection = new PDO($conn_string, $cred['username'], $cred['password'], $cred['options']);
                $time_to_connect = microtime(true) - $start;
                if ($time_to_connect > 0.1) {
                    $date_stamp      = date('Y-m-d H:i:s');
                    file_put_contents(__DIR__ . '/../../../../logs/connection.log', "[$date_stamp] Time to connect: $time_to_connect\r\n", FILE_APPEND);
                }
            }
            return self::$connection;
```

The host itself is the IP of the DB server, not the hostname, just to skip the hostname resolve. On a side note, the application usually has about 300 Mio Queries / hour > the error log does not show, that a query at any given moment can not be satisfied, so there is no timeout or something else. I just would like to know, why the time to connect is so flaky.

Let's have some of that log, to visualize, what exactly i am talking about:

```
[2021-11-23 08:42:53] Time to connect: 1.0140111446381
[2021-11-23 08:42:58] Time to connect: 0.20962715148926
[2021-11-23 08:43:35] Time to connect: 0.20882511138916
[2021-11-23 08:43:57] Time to connect: 1.0158820152283
[2021-11-23 08:44:04] Time to connect: 0.21016788482666
[2021-11-23 08:44:15] Time to connect: 0.20581793785095
[2021-11-23 08:44:34] Time to connect: 1.0257070064545
[2021-11-23 08:44:49] Time to connect: 0.2069239616394
[2021-11-23 08:45:16] Time to connect: 1.0137569904327
[2021-11-23 08:45:57] Time to connect: 0.20312690734863
[2021-11-23 08:46:37] Time to connect: 0.20860004425049
[2021-11-23 08:47:04] Time to connect: 0.21277403831482
[2021-11-23 08:47:19] Time to connect: 1.02792096138
[2021-11-23 08:47:42] Time to connect: 0.20777201652527
[2021-11-23 08:47:49] Time to connect: 0.20870685577393
```

I am using percona server version 8.

Comment: This is not an answer to your question, but have you considered using a connectioin pool instead of opening a new connection every time?

Comment: I did, as the PHP PDO supports a so called "ATTR_PERSISTENT" mode, but there was not a real difference between turning it on and off for a while. I appreciate the idea and input